# Standard Deviation in Statistics

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

**Problem:**

I'm really struggling with a really specific topic in statistics. It is working out the sample standard deviation when given summary statistics. I understand how to do the population standard deviation.

**Example Question:**

What is the sample standard deviation given the following information:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n x_k &= 80789\\
\sum_{k=0}^n x_k^2 &=113666365\\
n&=60
\end{align}$$

**Could someone please take me through the process of answering the question?**

Comment: @Clarinetist Can you help?

Comment: I would need more context: 1) do you know the shortcut formulas for the sample standard deviation and/or the population standard deviation, 2) if yes to 1) - have you been taught the algebra behind them, and 3) are you comfortable doing algebra with the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ symbols?

Comment: 1) I know the formula for both sample standard and population standard deviation but for sample standard deviation, I always somehow end up with the wrong answer 2) I've started Maths in college(UK) and we haven't gone in depth about the algebra behind them 3) No I am not

Comment: Notice that I said the **shortcut** formulas for the sample standard deviation and the population standard deviation. I am NOT referring to $S^2 = \dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$ and $\sigma^2 = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$. Have you been presented a **different, shortcut** formula for either of these? If so, please include it in your question. If not, reply here.

Comment: Clarinetist I didn't even know there were was a shortcut formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments in the OP, I believe this is a freshman undergraduate-level statistics course, where less emphasis is placed on algebraic derivations and solely on the algorithms for calculations. Thus, I will present the formula. If the algebra doesn't make any sense, don't worry about the algebra; the result is what matters.

The sample variance can be written as
$$\begin{align}
S^2 &= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - \bar{x})^2 \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k^2-2x_k\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2 - 2\bar{x}\sum_{k=1}^{k}x_k+ n\bar{x}^2\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2 - 2n\bar{x}^2+ n\bar{x}^2\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2 - n\bar{x}^2\right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Thus, $$S^2 = \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2-n\bar{x}^2 \right)$$
is the so-called "shortcut" formula for the sample variance. Note that $\bar{x} = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k}{n}$ is the sample mean. Simply put in the values you're provided to get the sample variance, and take the square root of the sample variance to get the sample standard deviation.

---

As a side note, you can obtain a similar formula for the population variance. Note the relationship
$$\sigma^2 = \dfrac{n-1}{n}S^2\text{.}$$
Thus,
$$\sigma^2 = \dfrac{n-1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2-n\bar{x}^2 \right) = \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2-n\bar{x}^2 \right)$$
Then, take the square root of $\sigma^2$ to obtain the population standard deviation.

Comment: So the answer would end up being 285.3454...

Comment: @coder80 I got 287.7.

Comment: @coder80 See this link: https://bit.ly/2DVTWFS

Comment: Clarinestist I've got it.Thanks for the help :)